# how to put button near the text box in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I already have one row

```
<div class="row input_section">
    <div class="span3">
        <h3>Origin</h3>
        <p>Where is the orinin of the delivery? Use to calculate price of delivery</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span9 delivery_section">
        <label><div>Address</div>
           <input type="text" name="type" value=""/>
        </label>
        <label>
            <button class="btn btn-primary"  type="button">Verify</button>
        </label>
        <label><div style="width:100%;height:150px;border:1px solid black;"></div></label>
    </div> 


</div>
```

And I want to do the div size full in the span9 .
So,How can i write it?

[image: googlemap]

Answer (score 2):

straight from the bootstrap docs my friend

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hSuy4/478/)

Bootstrap already have class `form-inline` to set into inline.
Use this in your existing div append this `class="form-inline"`

Replace this line

```
 <div class="span9 delivery_section">
```

into

```
 <div class="span9 delivery_section form-inline">
```

Already i use this, hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<div class="row input_section">
    <div class="span3">
        <h3>Origin</h3>
        <p>Where is the orinin of the delivery? Use to calculate price of delivery</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span9 delivery_section">
        <label>Address</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"> Verify </button>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%;height:150px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

If it doesn't seem to work, it probably because I'm using bootstrap 3.

Answer (score 0):

label is inline element. And moreover in bootstrap to accept the width by default they have specified the display property as **'block'**. Just override the code by placing the following code. Then you will done with your code.

```
label {
  display:inline-block;
}
```